# How do I include an aria-label on my IonCheckbox and still have the visible label render?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, accessibility, ionic7, ion-checkbox

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18. I have an IonCheckbox that I build like so

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel id="label1">Jeff Lebowski</IonLabel>
  <IonCheckbox value="123" checked={true} />
</IonItem>
```

This produces the accessibility warning

```bash
[Ionic Warning]: ion-checkbox now requires providing a label with 
either the default slot or the "aria-label" attribute. To migrate, 
remove any usage of "ion-label" and pass the label text to either 
the component or the "aria-label" attribute.
```

Example:

```html
<ion-checkbox>Label</ion-checkbox>
```

Example with aria-label:

```html
<ion-checkbox aria-label="Label"></ion-checkbox>
```

However, if I include an aria-label,

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel id="label1">Jeff Lebowski</IonLabel>
  <IonCheckbox value="123" checked={true} aria-label="Jeff Lebowski" />
</IonItem>
```

I can no longer see text next to my checkbox.  THe example of this is here -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-ef4kj7?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IonCheckbox value="123" checked={true}>
  Jeff Lebowski
</IonCheckbox>
```

seems to produce [the desired outcome](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-xx8ubi?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx).

---

In more detail, providing an `aria-label` is not the same with providing a `label`. `aria-label` is not rendered, it's used by screen readers to announce the checkbox. Whereas the slot contents (the `children` of `<ion-checkbox />`) are displayed as label.

The `ion-label` has been deprecated in favour of the two above. But each of them has its own separate purpose.

---

Note: if, for any reason, you want to use the old syntax, you can add `legacy={true}` to `<ion-checkbox />`, along with the `ion-label` attribute.